# Display plotly graph as image in Jupyterlab

Tags: plotly

Is there a way to plot a figure in plotly in jupyterlab/notebook as a simple image instead of an interactive chart?

I have some graphs that slow the notebook quite a bit and I dont always need the interactivity. Also, having a simple image would make it straightforward to copy and paste an image into an email by shift+right click and copy image.

Also, automatic uploading to confluence via nbconflux does not work with plotly charts whereas with matplotlib charts it works fine.

Bonus question:

If this is not possible, is there another way way to copy and paste a plotly chart from a notebook? The download as png option in the plotly graph task bar seems to mess up the height of the plots, so especially with a larger number of subplots it gets pretty squashed. Also, it seems to be inconsistent - the height to width ratio for graphs that are the same shape in jupyter can be very different when saved to png and so it is impossible to make it look even halfway professional using several graphs in one document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/

In summary, install `orca`, `psutils` and `requests`, then you can do something like this to display plotly figures as images:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import Image
fig = px.scatter(x=np.random.normal(size=100), y=np.random.normal(size=100))
Image(fig.to_image(format="png", width=600, height=350, scale=2))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: This is even faster / easier as of Plotly 4.9; you can just install `kaleido`, then perhaps add `engine="kaleido"` to `to_image()`.  [ref](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/)